# SML Binary Search Tree

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree, sml

So I have this datatype definition for a Binary Search Tree in SML:

```
datatype tree = Void | Node of tree * int * tree;
```

And I also have this function:

```
fun sub_tree a b Void = 
  | sub_tree a b (Node (t1, x, t2)) =
    if (a <= x) andalso (x < b) then
      Node ((sub_tree a b t1), x, (sub_tree a b t2))
    else
      sub_tree a b t2;
```

which is intended to go through the tree and yield another tree whose tags (x in the function) are greater or equal than a and smaller than b (a <= x < b).

Now I also have this example tree:

```
val ex1 = Node(Node(Node(Void, 0, Node(Void, 2, Void)), 3, Node(Void, 5, Void)), 6, Node(Void, 7, Node(Void, 8, Node(Void, 9, Node(Node(Void, 10, Void), 12, Node(Void, 15, Node(Void, 19, Void)))))))
```

So, the function works in the case of, for example:

```
sub_tree 5 8 ex1;
val it =  Node (Node (Void, 5, Void), 6, Node (Void, 7, Void)): tree
```

But when it doesn't work if a = 0 & b = 1, because:

```
sub_tree 0 1 ex1;
val it = Void: tree
```

And it should return: `Node (Void, 0, Void)`

So I need some help to point me the mistake(s) I made in the function, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide three cases in `sub_tree a b (Node (t1, x, t2))`:

- `a <= x andalso x < b`: include subbranch
- `x < a`: check right subbranch
- `b <= x`: check left subbranch

So to complete your function use:

```
if (a <= x) andalso (x < b) then
  Node ((sub_tree a b t1), x, (sub_tree a b t2))
else if x < a then
  sub_tree a b t2;
else
  sub_tree a b t1;
```

Visualisation of the three cases of `sub_tree a b (Node (t1, x, t2))`

```
       a, b <= x       |  a <= x andalso x < b  |       x < a, b
-----------------------+------------------------+----------------------
  x and t2 are to      |                        |  t1 and x are to
  the right of [a, b[  |  x lies within [a, b[  |  the left of [a, b[
  -> check t1          |  -> check t1 and t2    |  -> check t2
```

Comment: This is almost the exact solution I needed, but I tested it and it didn't work the way I intend it to.

However, it made me rethink my function, and I found the correct implementation:

`if (a <= x) andalso (x < b) then
  Node ((sub_tree a b t1), x, (sub_tree a b t2))
else if x < b then
  sub_tree a b t2;
else
  sub_tree a b t1;`

It now works just as I wanted it to, and it's thanks to your answer that I came up with the final solution, so thank you very much for your help.

(Edit): I don't know how to format the code accordingly in this comment, sorry.

Comment: Ah you're right, I've messed up the split: if `x >= b` then that means the open interval `[a, b[` may still contain `t1` but not `x` and not `t2`, on the other hand if `x < a` the interval cannot contain `t1`. See the edited version.